# How to intercept window close without mismatching with location change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, window.closed

I'm using `window.onbeforeunload` to intercept window close event. I've noticed that `window.onbeforeunload` is triggered even on location.href change and form submit.

I want to intercept only the event: "the user has closed the page".
How can I do it?

<sup>***I'm open to both JavaScript or jQuery solutions.*</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Comment: you could track the users ip/id backend and is the ip is not requesting an other page the window could have been closed.